# filling array with int and string same time

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{

    srand(time(NULL));

    char hex[]="0123456789ABCDEF";
    char seferNo[]="";
    char numaraDeposu[100][6];
    int j=0;
    for (j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        char seferNo[]="";
        for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
        {
            int a;
            a=(rand() % 15);
            strncat(seferNo,&hex[a],1);
        }
        strcpy(numaraDeposu[j],seferNo);

        printf("%s\n",numaraDeposu[j]);
    }
}
```

this works fine but i want number and string (code) in numaraDeposu
2 dimensional array first dimension is include int and second dimension include my random codes (perfect english)

1 (random code)
2 (random code)
3 (random code)
4 (random code)
like that

Comment: Declare a `struct` containing `int` and `char[]` and then declare an array of them.

Comment: `char seferNo[]="";` is an array of size `1` -- resulting in *Undefined Behavior* when `strncat(seferNo,&hex[a],1);` is called. see [man 3 strcat](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcat.3.html)

Comment: ..and there are two distinct `char seferNo[]="";` variables. The one inside the loop is shadowing the earlier one, which won't be seen inside the loop. Remove the inner one and change the earlier one to, say, `char seferNo[1000]="";`

Comment: Please take a little time to clarify what you want, **editing your question**. Do you want to also store a number along with the code, or you just want to output the number along with the random code? Moreover as pointed out by @DavidC.Rankin and you are totally in UB. Provide a size for that array.

Comment: _"this works fine"_.  I do not think this works fine:  `char seferNo[]="";`  It is an arrya of `char` with only enough room for one `char`, initialized to contain the `\0` char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, your `char seferNo[]="";` is an array of size 1, it can hold nothing but the empty string (`'\0'`) and still be treated as a string. Your call to `strncpy()` invokes *Undefined Behavior* because there is insufficient space for the `'\0'` character to be written.

You can do what you are attempting with a 2D array, and there is no need to include `string.h`. You can do it all with simple character operations and `stdio.h` `sprintf()`, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (void) {

    srand(time(NULL));

    const char hex[]="0123456789ABCDEF";
    char numaraDeposu[100][6] = {""};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        numaraDeposu[i][0] = hex[rand() % 16];
        sprintf (&numaraDeposu[i][1], "c%03d", rand()%1000);
        
        printf ("%s\n", numaraDeposu[i]);
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/numardeposu2D
Fc598
7c569
Ec247
1c451
Fc172
0c558
Bc501
0c462
Ec318
Ac396
2c742
0c304
4c146
...
```

---

**Use A struct When You Need An Object Holding Different Types**

Whenever you need to coordinate different types as a single object, you should be thinking `struct`. While here since you are limiting the 1st character in each string element of the 2D array to a single `char` it isn't entirely necessary. However, it will provide you with bit more flexibility in how you access the 1st character and the remaining code.

You can use a simple struct like:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char hexnum;
    char code[7];
} deposu_type;
```

An `unsigned char` was chosen simply to make the types different, but you can use `char` for both. You would then declare an array of struct and fill each member for each struct in the array, e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned char hexnum;
    char code[7];
} deposu_type;

int main (void) {

    srand(time(NULL));

    const char hex[]="0123456789ABCDEF";
    deposu_type numaraDeposu[100] = {{ .hexnum = 0 }};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        numaraDeposu[i].hexnum = hex[rand() % 16];
        sprintf (numaraDeposu[i].code, "c%03d", rand()%1000);
        
        printf ("%c %s\n", numaraDeposu[i].hexnum, numaraDeposu[i].code);
    }
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

Shown with a space between the `hexnum` and `code` members to emphasize the ease in referring to each member separately.

```
$ ./bin/numardeposu_struct
A c190
7 c329
D c955
7 c761
6 c968
D c781
8 c985
9 c449
7 c708
F c893
E c799
E c168
```

Both solutions are roughly equivalent, though using the `struct` and array of `struct` will be the simpler solution if your example becomes a bit more complex.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

---

**Allocating Storage Dynamically For As Many numaraDeposu As Needed**

In response to your comment on how to allocate storage for an infinite number of objects (which I will take as meaning an unknown number as you don't have infinite memory available), you will dynamically allocate storage to hold all `numaraDeposu` using `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`.

There is nothing difficult about dynamically allocating storage. To begin, you allocate storage for some reasonable number structures and you assign the address for the block of memory to your pointer variable. For example here, let's allocate storage for `2` struct `deposu_type` and assign the result to our pointer `numaraDeposu`, e.g.

```
    size_t  available = 2,      /* no. of struct available */
            used = 0;           /* no. of struct used */
    
    /* allocate memory for initial (2) struct available */
    deposu_type *numaraDeposu = malloc (available * sizeof *numaraDeposu);
    
    if (numaraDeposu == NULL) {             /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-numaraDeposu");
        return 1;
    }
```

(**note:** you must always check the return to validate that your allocation succeeded or failed and handle any failure)

You always keep two counter variables for your allocation. The `available` counter holds the number of `numaraDeposu` that can currently fit in the allocated block of memory, and `used` tracks the number you have filled (used). When `(used == available)` you reallocate a larger block of memory and update the number `available`. A common growth pattern is to double the number available each time you need more, but you are free to add as many or as few each time as you like.

A simple example that allocated storage for `numaraDeposu` could be written as follows. With this approach, you can allocate for as many `numaraDeposu` as you need until you run out of physical memory:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned char hexnum;
    char code[7];
} deposu_type;

int main (void) {

    const char hex[]="0123456789ABCDEF";
    size_t  available = 2,      /* no. of struct available */
            used = 0;           /* no. of struct used */
    
    srand(time(NULL));
    
    /* allocate memory for initial (2) struct available */
    deposu_type *numaraDeposu = malloc (available * sizeof *numaraDeposu);
    
    if (numaraDeposu == NULL) {             /* validate EVERY allocation */
        perror ("malloc-numaraDeposu");
        return 1;
    }
    
    for (; used < 100; used++) {
        if (used == available) {    /* reallocate more when (used == available) */
            /* always reallocate using temporary pointer */
            void *tmp = realloc (numaraDeposu, 2 * available * sizeof *numaraDeposu);
            if (!tmp) {                     /* valdate EVERY reallocation */
                perror ("realloc-numaraDeposu");
                break;
            }
            numaraDeposu = tmp;     /* assign reallocated block to pointer */
            available *= 2;         /* updaate no. of struct available */
        }
        numaraDeposu[used].hexnum = hex[rand() % 16];
        sprintf (numaraDeposu[used].code, "c%03d", rand()%1000);
        
        printf ("%c %s\n", numaraDeposu[used].hexnum, numaraDeposu[used].code);
    }
    
    free (numaraDeposu);            /* free all allocated memory */
}
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/numardeposu_struct_dyn
==13231== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==13231== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==13231== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==13231== Command: ./bin/numardeposu_struct_dyn
==13231==
C c582
A c524
4 c742
1 c697
5 c890
...
6 c509
A c079
2 c511
0 c770
==13231==
==13231== HEAP SUMMARY:
==13231==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==13231==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 3,056 bytes allocated
==13231==
==13231== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==13231==
==13231== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==13231== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: thank you it helped soo much can i ask something. i want to declare infinite number of (struct) busses for my code and every bus have an hex num queue num ect. but i dont know how to declare infinite number of struct (user can add busses)

Comment: hope you understand my poor english

Comment: The way you declare any object in a way you can add or remove storage for additional objects is to declare a pointer of that type and then allocate storage for however many you need at the time using `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()` and then when you need to increase or decrease the amount of storage, you use `realloc()` to adjust the size of the memory block.